# Android: Image doesn't show if textfield is long

Tags: android, android-layout

I got this layout of my messaging-app: (It is the layout of my listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:gravity="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_message"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip">

        <github.ankushsachdeva.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ProgramTitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wait"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But if the message gets long and it gets two lined, the "tick" (id=messageIcon) disappears:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why? How can I fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cause of your problem is with regards on how you set the anchor for your `ImageView`. You have all of these:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Which kinda messes up the anchoring. Here are the descriptions as per docs of [RelativeLayout.Params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

`layout_toRightOf`:

> Positions the left edge of this view to the right of the given anchor view ID.

`layout_alignBottom`:

> Makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID.

`layout_alignParentBottom`:

> If true, makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the parent.

If the behavior you are aiming for your `ImageView` is for it to be set always just to be on the lower right corner (just below) the `TextView`, you can try this out:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />
```

Here's an initial screenshot:

[image]

Here's what it looks like if the text line is more than 1:

[image]

For more information on how `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` behave, just see the link I mentioned above. Hope this helps. Good luck and Happy coding. ;)

PS: If you were aiming for a different behavior, just leave a comment and I'll edit the answer. ;)

> **EDIT**

As per your comment, the width now takes up space the same as the parent.. So I modified the code, and managed to simplify it further. Instead of using a `RelativeLayout` for the first child view, I just used a `LinearLayout`, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            android:text="Program\nTitasdfasdfasdfa"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**TIP**: I think the outermost layout (main parent `LinearLayout`) is no longer needed. I think you can just remove it to avoid unnecessary `overDraw`.

> **EDIT 2**

Here's my test code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.my.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Program\nTitasdfasdfasdfa"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/list_item_text_view"
                android:layout_below="@id/list_item_text_view"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Program\nTitasdfasdfasdfa"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/messageIcon2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/list_item_text_view2"
                android:layout_below="@id/list_item_text_view2"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

> **EDIT 3**

So as per the comments, you added another `TextView` and had another issue with the alignment.. So I went ahead and tried it out, and the easiest layout I can make for the behavior you wanted was using a `LinearLayout`. See below code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Pro"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Timestamp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In this layout, the `timestamp` and `messageIcon` will stay beside each other and below the `list_item_text_view`. I was having issues on how to implement it in the `RelativeLayout`, because of the alignment; setting the alignments like `alignParentRight` to true causes the Layout itself to maximize. Will still try to do this using `RelativeLayout` if I have free time, since using a `RelativeLayout` is better to avoid too much ***OverDraw***. Hope this helps you somehow tho. Good luck!

Comment: This in fact works. BUT the message-window has now a width of 100%. I just want it to cover the text. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: If ever you still prefer to use `RelativeLayout` rather than the `LinearLayout`, you can just replace the `alignParentRight="true"` to `android:layout_alignRight="@id/list_item_text_view"` ;)

Comment: It is still width=100%. And another problem is, that I change programmatically the gravity of the row_message linearlayout, so that the message some times is on the left side, sometimes on the right side. But with this missing, that doesn't work.

Comment: Now it works. I copied your code. I must have made some mistake when editing it before. Thank you very much. It works very well :-)

Comment: One more question: If I add this to the layout: <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Timestamp"
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_text_view"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />  then the "row_message" is to small when the text is short. So the word "timestamp" is written vertically, how to prevent that

Comment: are you still using `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`?

Comment: If you're still using `RelativeLayout`, use this for the ***timestamp*** `TextView`:
`<TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_text_view"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Timestamp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />`

Comment: Then modify your `ImageView`, remove `layout_alignRight` and `layout_below`, then add:

`android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timestamp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timestamp"`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but now if the message is long the timestamp+image is on the left side, not on the right :/

Comment: I currently can't try it out, since I'm currently away. I'll try it next time. But have you tried setting the `gravity` of the `RelativeLayout` to `right`?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I tried, but this won't work. But the RelativeLayout means the whole thing. I just want the timestamp+img to be on the right side.

Comment: I'll get back here as soon as I can test it. ;)

Comment: @progNewbie I edited my answer.. Try it out if you have time. Good luck.